# Protect a single subdomain on a Multisite

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, password-protection

I have a Wordpress Multisite running with subdomains and Domain Mappings.

the domains are configured as Serveralias.

```
ServerAlias *.domain1.tld *.domain2.tld *.domain3.tld
```

basically I am trying to help with a new template and would like

```
dev.domain.tld
```

to be accessible only via authentication

generally I'd use somethng like:

```
AuthUserFile /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Area 51"
AuthType Basic

<limit GET POST>
    require valid-user
</limit>

<Files *>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Satisfy any
</Files>
```

But this would protect all (sub)domains at once. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try setting a variable checking the **Host** header field, and not authenticating if the host isn't dev.domain.tld:

```
SetenvIfNoCase Host dev.domain.tld devhost=yes

<limit GET POST>
    Satisfy Any
    require valid-user
    Allow from env=!devhost
</limit>
```

The `Satisfy Any` makes it so either the `require` or the `Allow` is good enough for access. If `devhost` env is set, then the `Allow` check fails and the only way to gain access is with a valid-user.

Comment: Just posting the complete code:

`SetenvIfNoCase HOST sub\.domain\.tld PROTECTED_HOST

AuthUserFile /var/www/vhosts/mmo-game.eu/httpdocs/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Developer Area"
AuthType Basic

<limit GET POST>
 Order Deny,Allow
 Satisfy any
 Deny from all
 Require valid-user
 Allow from env=!PROTECTED_HOST
</limit>`